# Add or subtract to a column

Tags: java, arrays, rest, sum, 2d

How can I add 1 or subtract 1 to a column in a 2D array?
I have a 5x5 2D Array and need to add or subtract 1 to the column the user wants to change
Thanks for any answers

Comment: Please add a tag to indicate which programming language you're talking about.

Comment: Sorry about that, its in java

Comment: I don't see any code you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the user is going to give you a column number and then you are supposed to subtract one from every element in that column?

If that's your question, you can solve this with a simple loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    myArray[i][column]--;
}
```